# Custom Theme for recapcha in Mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating Recaptcha in MVC 2.0. I used following code to create Captcha..

```
public static class Captcha
{
    public static string GenerateCaptcha(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {

        var captchaControl = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl
                {
                    ID = "recaptcha",
                    Theme = "blackglass",
                    PublicKey = "000000",
                    PrivateKey = "00000"
                };

        captchaControl.Theme = "white";


        var htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter());

        captchaControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        return htmlWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }

}
```

Here I used a white theme which is already available in Recaptcha. I want to create my own theme and implement it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your solutions from below blog and links:-

http://chenz101tutorials.blogspot.com/2009/08/customize-recaptcha-remove-theme-aspnet.html

http://captcha.biz/doc/asp.net/2.0/csharp/asp.net-mvc-captcha-code-sample.html

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1567/recaptcha/

Comment: Thanks, can there is no other way that i can make the theme  on code behind?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.